# wordpress-passing variable from front-page.php to javascript

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to access variable in javascript, that is passed from `front-page.php` file. I have this in `front-page.php`

```
 ...
 function pass_var_to_js() {
 $my_variable="test php var";
wp_enqueue_script('sample', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/sample.js', array(), '1.0', false);
wp_localize_script('sample','jsObject', [
    'myVar' => $my_variable ]);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pass_var_to_js');
add_action('wp_body_open', 'pass_var_to_js');
...
...
<?php
    wp_body_open();
?>
```

and in javascript file I have

```
console.log(jsObject.myVar);
```

But it does not print variable on console

When I put the same code in `functions.php` , it works and prints  `test php var` on console

How can I can pass some variables from `front-page.php` to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The issue was that , I needed to add

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pass_var_to_js');
  wp_head();
```

in the `<head>` section of `front-page.php`

this `function pass_var_to_js()` can remain in the body part

After above changes , I did not needed this `add_action('wp_body_open', 'pass_var_to_js');`